# Changing info on a different sheet in the same spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two ranges of equal size on different sheets in the same spreadsheet. I am trying to find a row (based off of user input) in the first sheet and then use that index to modify a table in the second sheet that counts how many times that certain index has been used before (to make a nice looking pie chart).

This code runs but will not produce results on the second sheet. I've gone through the debugging process and my best guess is that for some reason, my for in loop is not running through. Attached is my code that takes in the beforementioned index and attempts to perform the second half of my goal.

```
function acceptToEncounterChart(ghostrow) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]);
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Average Encounter Chart");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B3:B14")
  
  for(var i in range) {
    if(ghostrow == i) {
      var before = range[i][0].getValue()
      range[i][0].setValue(before + 1);
    } 
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
};
```

Comment: What is the value of `ghostrow`. Don't you think it is an important information to debug your code? Also if you are not sure whether a block of code is executed, use `Logger.log("I am executed")` inside the `if` block of the `for` loop. This will help you spot where the issue is and help both you and us resolve it.

Comment: @Marios ghostrow holds the index correctly. As I stated in the message, I'm pretty sure the for isn't running as I already did what you said. My question is why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

I am not entirely sure what is your goal.

However, here is some **fixes / improvements** starting from the beginning:

- You define 2 times the same variable `ss` with exactly the same value.
- You don't need to set the active sheet, if your goal is to just get the sheet, therefore this line is redundant:

  `SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]);`
- Variable `range` is **not an array** but a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object. You **can't** index it and therefore you **can't** also use a for loop to iterate over a **single** object. For the same exact reason, the code inside the if statement is wrong, you **can't** index `range`. But you don't see any errors because the `if` statement evaluates to `false`.
- In JavaScript and in many other programming languages, array indexes start from `0`. Since your range starts from cell `B3` or row `3`, you need to use `i+3` to match the data with the range.
- For the same reason as the previous point, `ghostrow` is an **index**, not a **row**. The `if` statement compares an array index `i` with `ghostrow`, so `ghostrow` should not be confused with the actual sheet row. For example, if you choose `ghostrow=5` then the current script will increment the value of the cell `B8` (remember `i+3`) by 1.

---

### Solution:

Here is a workable code snippet:

```
function acceptToEncounterChart(ghostrow) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Average Encounter Chart");
  var data = sheet.getRange("B3:B14").getValues().flat();
  
  data.forEach((v,i)=>{
   if(ghostrow == i){
    sheet.getRange(i+3,2).setValue(v+1)
  }              
  });
 ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

---

### Related:

Please explore the [official google apps script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials).

Comment: ahh, my brain just thought that since I set the range to my table, it would just default the B3 row to 0 index. I was trying to loop through the range object because I didn't look close enough at the documentation. thanks for clearing it up.